# When's Groovy EOL

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions/Timeline#End_of_Life

> ROS releases will be supported on the associated Ubuntu platforms while the Ubuntu platform remains supported.

This sounds to me that `Groovy` will survive until April 2017 when [Ubuntu `Precise` will become EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). Is that the plan?

(And regarding `Precise` I'm assuming that `fuerte` was already terminated because it was released before REP-3 (or related) was updated.)

Personally from my experience, Groovy is where the mixture of 2 build systems was officially introduced and build-release work needs additional care and chores for some packages. So I doubt if it's worth keeping it so long (but on the other hand I'm strongly in favor of the idea of `LTS`. I just feel Groovy might not have to be it).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152551/when%27s-groovy-eol/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2014-04-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is *not* the case. Groovy will be EOLed when Indigo is officially released which is planned for next month. Practically we might keep the buildfarm for Groovy running until we spin up builds for J turtle which might be a bit after the Indigo release (but better don't rely on that).

The policy has always been that we maintain two released ROS distributions plus a third one being in development. Indigo will be the first release which we call an LTS - so we aim to maintain it for quite some time (for the "lifetime" of the corresponding Ubuntu release Trusty).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1